# How set the image on the top of UISpliteViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I want to set image at the navigation controller bar 
after adding the code it look like bellow 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is setting an image for `UINavigationBar`. For this, you need this code :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "imageBackground")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .Stretch), forBarMetrics: .Default)
}
```

It will set your image called `imageBackground` as the background for your `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: hello Anthonin  how we add button which shown at right and a lable named GYm Name